# CURL request in iOS

Tags: ios, curl, request

I'm trying to make use of the CO-OP API for some purposes in my app (http://coopapp.com/api)

I know how to preform the request using curl:

```
curl http://coopapp.com/groups/20/statuses -H 'Accept: application/xml' \ -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -u email:password
```

But I can't figure out how to do this in iOS, hopefully somebody can give me a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do that with the `NSURLConnection` class. But I recommend using [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit/) which is a handy wrapper around it. It actually even shows the equivalent `curl` command in the description of its operations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked the examples, but I can't seem to find the curl command in there

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the same web page use UIWebView,Same HTML page will be loaded

Comment: I don't want to load the webpage, I want to make a curl request so it returns the XML or JSON